# I cannot find my curve in my graphic editor

Tags: animation

I had just begun using animation and once I changed my viewpoint to graphic editor, I could not find my curve. My graph itself seems off since the top is giving me -900000.., and the sides a similar digit. I’m trying to have the top to range from 100s (100,200 etc) and the side to range from 20s (0,20,40 etc). I had tried using the home key but I use a Mac so I’m guessing the home key is fn + left arrow. I did click on the graph and pressed those keys however nothing happened. I’m not sure how to fix this. Is there a manual section I can input what I want for the y-axis and the x-axis? What should I do?[image]

Comment: did u change your default keymap settings? i just can assume that you assigned the home button to another function. I am MacUser as well and the home button works with fn+left exactly as you wrote.

Comment: the "brute force" method to repair would be to go in settings -> keymap -> graph editor, then press "restore" [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMB02.png -> but be aware: you will loose all your "manual made" keymaps

Comment: you've zoomed out and scrolled a lot, what does it give if you select all (A) and press the numpad dot (.)?

Comment: you can search in keymap for "HOME": [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jyrv.png

Comment: @moonboots, I tried to click A + (.) and it gave me a pivot menu (bounce box center, 2d cursor, and individual center).

Comment: then you can check, whether "home" in graph editor is defined, if yes, search for other "Home" definitions

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Chris thank you so much it worked. I had been pressing on End ( fn + right arrow) all this while. I appreciate the honesty.

Comment: @moonboots, thank you for the assist, I had been pressing the wrong key the whole time. Thank you so much once again.

Answer (score 0):

You've zoomed out and scrolled a lot, to automatically come back to the existing keyframes select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) then press the numpad dot key (<kbd>.</kbd>).